# Promotion being applied multiple times automatically

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, promotions

I have a promo code where users can get $10 off $20+. The code applies correctly for 1 item. But it also applies for every $20 in your cart. $40 in your cart means $20 discount, etc.
Do I have something configured incorrectly?

[image: magento promo conditions]
[image: magento promo actions]

I'm running CE 1.9.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Actions pane, try updating "Apply" to "fixed amount discount for whole cart" instead of "fixed amount discount"

Comment: That seems to fix it. Those 2 options "fixed amount" and "fixed amount...whole cart" seem like the same option to me.